# Best way to define a configuration object using Google Closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-compiler

I love how Google Closure compiler will optimize symbols in code.  However, I have not found a good way to define public, exported functions that take configuration objects as parameters.  Consider this code snippet:

```
goog.provide('foo');
goog.require('goog.dom');

/** @typedef {{
 *              id : string,
 *              clazz : string
 *           }}
 */
foo.config;

/**
 * Does some neat stuff
 * @param {foo.config} config
 */    
foo.myFoo = function(config) {
    var el = goog.dom.getElement(config.id);
    goog.dom.classes.add(el, config.clazz);
} 
goog.exportSymbol('foo.myFoo', foo.myFoo);
```

Now assume we load this script, and want to call myFoo as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
foo.myFoo({
    id: 'unique-id',
    clazz: 'pretty'
});
</script>
```

If compiled, this would fail because id and clazz properties were compressed.

Does anyone know of an elegant way to implement and export configuration objects using the Google Closure compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to simply annotate the parameter as `{Object}` and quote the keys, as below:

```
foo.myFoo({
    'id': 'unique-id',
    'clazz': 'pretty'
});

...

/**
 * Does some neat stuff
 * @param {Object} config
 */    
foo.myFoo = function(config) {
    var el = goog.dom.getElement(config['id']);
    goog.dom.classes.add(el, config['clazz']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to solve the same problem and this worked. But I'm not sure I understand why the compiler obfuscates the property names when dot notation is used, but not when square bracket notation is used. I know square bracket notation permits variables, but wouldn't the compiler obfuscate those too?

Comment: Why change the param to "Object"? His type definition was fine, all he had to do was either declare an extern or use a string literal: `config['id']` instead of `config.id`. Removing the proper type definition means that if he ever called the function from within his compiled code, he wouldn't have any type checking. Defeats the point, no?

Comment: My understanding of annotation is that it is used for humans to make sense of a method much like a more elegant comment line. More importantly, it allows google to throw errors if that method was used improperly.

Answer (score 1):

*Regarding conflicts of mangled and raw property names*

You'll have to either:

- "extern" your property names (so that they won't be renamed)
- use "bracketed notation" to access propertiies

*Regarding configuration objects*

According to the Closure Compiler docs, currently you can't do it.  You have to mark the param as Object.

You *may* define a type, but it won't help you because a type requires *all* the properties to exist, but you may only set a few parameters in a configuration object.

The Closure Compiler documentation recommends that you mark the parameter as Object, but document the fields in comments.